# JMeter - IBM BPM - different HTML and response data

Tags: jmeter, response, business-process-management

I need to retrieve info I see on the HTML rendered by IBM BPM but it doesn't appear on the Response Data tab on JMeter. this is ther html:

```
<div class="outputTextLabel">
    <label class="text controlLabel" dir="ltr"></label>
</div>
<span class="text">

    196360

</span>
```

and I need to retrieve the "196360", BUT the response data on JMeter reads:

```
           <div class="outputTextLabel">
<label class="text controlLabel"></label>
```

so there's no way to retrieve the number since JMeter is not capturing the rendered HTML

any help please?

thanks

Comment: Can you show your Test plan ? and zoom on the sampler in error ?

Answer (score 2):

JMeter is unlikely to work for you to test IBM BPM.  Quoting from the JMeter site -

> In particular, JMeter does not execute the Javascript found in HTML pages.

The new IBM BPM control framework relies heavily on using DoJo to update the control after initial rendering to fully populate all the information.  A test tool that cannot run the client side JS is unlike to work.  I strongly recommend you look at Selenium or a similar browser based testing tool.

(Note:  I don't think Selenium recommends you use them for performance testing)

Basically what JMeter is returning to you is what is initially sent down the wire before all the client side JS executes to fully populate the UI.